# Where is a good place to find maven archetypes?

Tags: maven-2, repository, archetypes

I'm aware of the archetype list in [codehaus](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List).  Are there any other good places to find Maven archetypes out there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the URLs of all the Maven Archetype catalogs that you know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635543/what-are-the-urls-of-all-the-maven-archetype-catalogs-that-you-know-about)